# Will old Apple Watch models work with AirPower?

Tags: apple-watch, charging

Apple showed off its AirPower charging mat with an Series 3 Apple Watch. Will AirPower work with older Apple Watch models as well?

Comment: See this article for some info  https://www.macworld.com/article/3224389/mobile-accessories/apple-airpower-features-specs-price-faq.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no** unfortunately.

https://www.macrumors.com/2017/09/20/airpower-apple-watch-series-3/

https://www.apple.com/watch/compare/

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

> AirPower works with the new series 3 Apple Watch, as well as the Apple
>   Watch Series 2, the original Apple Watch, the Appel Watch Edition,
>   Apple Watch Hermes, and the Apple Watch Nike+.

https://www.macworld.com/article/3224389/mobile-accessories/apple-airpower-features-specs-price-faq.html